# MVC framework to extend AbstractController, AbstractModel

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, frameworks

I am trying to learn MVC through [this paper](http://www.midmarsh.co.uk/planetjava/tutorials/swing/Tables-and-MVC.PDF) but in the example some classes extend AbstractModel or AbstractController, and I guess I need to download an MVC framework. Is it available? Where?

```
package citation;
import mvc.AbstractController;

public class CitationController extends AbstractController {
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is many MVC Framework that exist... in many languages.

You could also make your own MVC.

I think the example suppose you created a package "mvc" and a "AbstractController" class in it.

Comment: ok, therefore i guess the example is quite useless to learn :(